# TypeScript generic gives Argument of type X is not assignable to parameter of type 'never' error

Tags: typescript, generics

I have the following in a React component:

```
  type FormState = {
    size: Array<'small' | 'medium' | 'large' | 'xlarge'>;
    gender: Array<'male' | 'female'>;
  };

  const [form, setForm] = useState<FormState>({
    size: ['small', 'medium', 'large', 'xlarge'],
    gender: ['male', 'female']
  });

  function handleUpdateArray<T extends 'size' | 'gender'>(
    key: T,
    value: FormState[T]
  ): void {
    const isEnabled = form[key].includes(value); // <-- first error

    const newValue = isEnabled
      ? form[key].filter((val) => val !== value) // <-- second error
      : [...form[key], value];

    setForm((prevForm) => ({
      ...prevForm,
      [key]: newValue
    }));
  }
```

I'm calling the handler function like so:

```
  handleUpdateArray<'gender'>('gender', 'male');
```

But am getting the following errors:

```
(parameter) value: ("small" | "medium" | "large" | "xlarge")[] | ("male" | "female")[]
Argument of type '("small" | "medium" | "large" | "xlarge")[] | ("male" | "female")[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
  Type '("small" | "medium" | "large" | "xlarge")[]' is not assignable to type 'never'.
```

and:

```
This expression is not callable.
  Each member of the union type '{ <S extends "small" | "medium" | "large" | "xlarge">(predicate: (value: "small" | "medium" | "large" | "xlarge", index: number, array: ("small" | "medium" | "large" | "xlarge")[]) => value is S, thisArg?: any): S[]; (predicate: (value: "small" | ... 2 more ... | "xlarge", index: number, array: ("small" | ... 2 more...' has signatures, but none of those signatures are compatible with each other.ts(2349)
```

How can I get it to work?

Comment: What is `FormStateT`?

Comment: @Anatoly sorry that was a typo, updated it. Should have been `FormState`

Comment: `size` and `gender` arrays have nothing in common and that leads to `never`

Comment: Is this specific to react? If so I guess the question should be tagged as such. If not then maybe you could [edit] the question not to depend on third-party libraries